# what is the purpose of database level trigger in the DDL trigger?

Tags: sql-server

I am confused that what is the on database in the below trigger what is the purpose of using that please let me know what is the use of that

```
create  trigger trmyfirsttrigger
on database
for create_table,alter_table,drop_table
as
begin
   rollback
   print 'you can not create ,alter,drop table.'
end
```

Comment: The `PRINT` statement tells you the intent; so that  *"you can not create ,alter,drop table[s]"*. What are you unclear on here?

Comment: I know that but what is the purpose of on database in the above trigger?

Comment: Because it's not on a specific table, it's on the whole database?? Side note: this trigger is probably better written with a `THROW` and no `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: it means I can use this DDL trigger for all tables. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The trigger is defined at the database level and is intended to prevent any create, alter and drop statements on any table. That means you cannot create a new table, alter or delete existing tables on the database. This is generally used by DBAs to lock the database from any changes during maintenance & patching.